# Building two projects in a solution but only 1 gets into drop folder

Tags: azure-pipelines

Have a solution with 5 projects.  Two of which need to be built and published as individual artifacts for deployment.  (1) .net framework web app and (1) .net framework windows service

The archive for the service project shows up in the drop folder, but not the web app.  What have I messed up?

My yaml file

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  mySvc: '**/my.svcproj.srvc/my.svcproj.srvc.csproj'
  myWeb: '**/my.webapp.Web/my.webapp.Web.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

# srvc
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(mySvc)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(Build.BuildId)\srvc"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# srvc
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(Build.BuildId)\srvc'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)-srvc.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

# web
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(myWeb)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

[ update 1] 
As a test, I took out the steps for the svc and left the web build.  Im getting this in the build log

> ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(778,5):
> Warning : The OutputPath property is not set for project
> 'my.webapp.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have
> specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this
> project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be
> seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without
> a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
> Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

The relevant csproj section looks like this

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using PublishBuildArtifacts try using [PublishPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

This is recommended as PublishBuildArtifacts will be eventually replaced with PublishPipelineArtifact with the direction of moving towards more pipelines.  This should publish everything for you.

Comment: I think I must have the paths off somehow to my web project.  See update above

Comment: ok, after fixing a few things, I got it working.  The paths dont look right, but the output is there.